# Musical Rebus Challenge!

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus, music

These rebuses are rebuses of songs. Most of them require lateral-thinking, however, some are clear cut logic. Give the name of the song, and the band/artist, plus the album (or single) and release date.
[image]

Comment: D has been updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

B.

> (You)(ng) and (Men)(ace) by Fall Out Boy, "Mania", April 27th 2017. If this is right, I still have no idea about the middle part other than the letter D. I'm hoping carryout and Italy somehow mean "an".

Edit: Included full song info.

Comment: Yes! You solved it! That D is its actually "AND". The top part is "takeout" food, but its also known as a "to go". "To go" (as in leave) in Italian is ANDARE. You then divide that by D, or RE in DoReMi, leaving you with just AND. But Well done! Can you just list the Album/Single title, release date, etc as listed on the instructions?

Comment: Nice Job. Though I do prefer Fall Out Boy's "American Beauty American Psycho" Album than the new Mania Album. Too electric-y for me.

Answer (score 8):

A:

> (H) (opel astra) (s) (opus the penguin) = Hopeless Opus, Imagine Dragons, Smoke + Mirrors, February 17, 2015 with help from phoog

B:

> (you)(ng) (takeout) (italy) / (D) (suave) (snoopy) :

C:

> Foil, Weird Al, Mandatory Fun, ‎July 15, 2014

F:

> Shower by Becky G in 2014 (It is a single, not an album) from Quantum Twinkie

Comment: C weird al answer correct. F is close

Comment: A is on the right track! Just tweak it a little...

Comment: A: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGnTR_oEFt4 -- rot13: u(bcry)(rff) bchf

Comment: B like half of it correct. Other half wrong track

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer

A

> Hopeless Opus, Imagine Dragons, Smoke + Mirrors, February 17, 2015, from **phoog**, and **Jordan.J.D**.

B

> The beginning is *young* with Italy takeout over D for tunning? With help from**Gustavo Gabriel**.

C

> Foil, Weird Al, Mandatory Fun, ‎July 15, 2014 by **Jordan.J.D**

D

> Despacito (“Slowly”), Luis Fonsi ft. Daddy Yankee, Single, January 12, 2017, from **TrojanByAccident**

E

> *Sky Full of Stars* by Coldplay, 2014, and album Ghost Stories.

F

> *Shower* by Becky G in 2014 (It is a single, not an album)

Comment: Your D is actually the B one right? And I thought that also could mean "young"...

Comment: Your F is correct. Its a single, so you don't really need an album. Just say (its a single, so album does not apply) The rest is incorrect. You're on the completely wrong track for D, though. Your E is kind of on the right track.

Comment: You E is correct! Nice!

Comment: C has already been answered by @JordanJ.D.

Comment: Oooooh you ***ARE SOOOO CLOSE*** to solving B!!!

Comment: young..takeout.. young buck media takeout? google didn't make that one easy.

Comment: in B that guy is from suave hair product ads, and the last dog is snoopy from Peanuts comic strip / Charlie Brown cartoon.

Comment: The guy is not suave

Answer (score 6):

A, with a nod to [Jordan.J.D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61792/18224), is

> Hopeless Opus, Imagine Dragons, Smoke + Mirrors, February 17, 2015

Comment: Great Job! That is correct

Answer (score 6):

Is perhaps D

> Despacito (“Slowly”), Luis Fonsi ft. Daddy Yankee, Single, January 12, 2017

Comment: Nice! It is correct!

Answer (score 5):

Just a partial answer to help anyone who is trying to solve these:

A:

> Golden Age(H)

B:

> Young (that n makes a ng sound)

Comment: B (yes part of it is young) but A is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Is:

A.

> "(Do You Love Me) Just Say Yes" from the album Highway 101 by Bob DiPiero.

D.

> ?

Comment: No, no wrong direction. Try not to think about the turtle itself but maybe what it does?

Answer (score 1):

B:

> young wild and free by snoop dogg ?

(not sure about how all the pictures fit in)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil your solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!